# How to insert with select using GORM?

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

Is there a way to insert(create) rows with select in a single query using GORM?

What I am trying to do is to join two tables and insert rows into another table using a selected value from the table (using insert/select) but I'm having a hard time finding a way to call create along with select using GORM.

Basically what I hope to do can be done in a below SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO table_two (val, name, age)
SELECT table_one.some_value, '', 0
FROM table_one
WHERE table_one.some_value = 50
```

This inserts new rows into `table_two` with `val` column values set to the `some_value` of each of the matched rows in `table_one`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement your request in two ways.
The first approach is to use a raw SQL Query (the same that you provide in your question). Thanks to the `db.Exec()` function you're able to run a raw SQL statement against your MySQL instance.
The second approach is to split the operation into two parts:

1. First you read the data with `Where` and `Find`
2. Second you insert the data with `Create`

Below, you can find both solutions:

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type TableOne struct {
    SomeValue int
    Name      string
    Age       int
}

type TableTwo struct {
    Val  int
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    // refer https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#dsn-data-source-name for details
    dsn := "root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/todo?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // first approach - Raw SQL
    if dbTrn := db.Exec(`INSERT INTO table_twos (val, name, age)
    SELECT table_ones.some_value, '', 0
    FROM table_ones
    WHERE table_ones.some_value = 50`).Error; dbTrn != nil {
        panic(dbTrn.Error)
    }

    // second approach - split into two actions
    var recordsOne []TableOne
    recordsTwo := make([]TableTwo, 0)
    db.Where("some_value=?", 50).Find(&recordsOne)
    for _, v := range recordsOne {
        recordsTwo = append(recordsTwo, TableTwo{Val: v.SomeValue, Name: "", Age: 0})
    }
    db.Create(&recordsTwo)
}
```

Let me know if this works also for you.

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping there is a way to do it in a single call rather than two separate queries (as in your second approach). 
Using a raw query would work but I’d prefer to utilize the GORM API if possible.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't know any other way to accomplish this as you wish. I'll keep an eye on this post to see if someone else provides another solution.